# Catch exception from controller in Window.open using Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

I have a controller, which is used to flush the bytes, which inturn will generate the PDF on the client side. But, if an exception occurs, I want to catch that and show some appropriate message to the user.

I tried Ajax, but Ajax uses only JSON, String or XML for message exchange format. How can I handle this conditon?

I have to generate the pdf in success case or catch the exception. Here is my controller and javascript code

```
try {
    MyUtil.generatePdf(response, documentBytes, "DU"); // --> This method will flush the bytes
} catch (Exception e) {
    result.setStatus("EXCEPTION OCCURED.");
}
return result;
```

### Generate pdf method

```
public static void GeneratePdf(HttpServletResponse response, byte[] documentBytes, 
                               String fileName) {

    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + fileName + ".pdf");
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, postcheck=0, pre-check=0");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
    response.setContentLength(documentBytes.length);
    ServletOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = response.getOutputStream();
        out.write(documentBytes);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

### Javascript code

```
try {
    window.open("http://localhost:8080/INQ/CBU/5559901410151HELMPFN");

} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you can do this with `window.open()`.

My suggestion is to use servlet API in a way that you either download the PDF or in case of an error show an error page to the user.

I have some test code for exactly the scenario in which either the PDF is written out OR an error page is sent to the user with an error message.

The clue is that an exception is caught and in that case an error message is sent out to the user using a different encoding.

### servlet code

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet("/download")
public class PDFServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            String fileName = "asset_report1.pdf"; // Dummy file
            // This throws sometimes an exception.
            byte[] documentBytes = MyUtil.generatePdf(fileName);
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + fileName);
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            expireCache(response);
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
            response.setContentLength(documentBytes.length);
            ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            out.write(documentBytes);
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            expireCache(response);
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                    "The PDF file could not be retrieved.");
        }
    }

    private void expireCache(HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, postcheck=0, pre-check=0");
    }

}
```

This works out pretty well. Either you get the PDF downloaded OR you get an error page. You will need to eventually work on you error page to make it look pretty, but the default error page is a start.

Sometimes you see the PDF and in case of an error the default error page:

[image]

Comment: @This is not the case, I want to catch the exception and customise the message and show it in some modal window.

Answer (score 0):

In your case its best to get the pdf response as arraybuffer in angular side and store it as a blob and then download it. You can do it making a post rquest to the server. And add a error block in your angular code.

Server Side Code..

```
    List<PhysicalCountEntityTo> salaryList = exportNonDashBoardReportManager.fetchSalaryDetails(payloadBean);
    HashMap<String, Object> parametersPDF = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDataSource = null;
    beanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(salaryList);
    String reportPath = httpServletRequest.getServletContext().getRealPath("//WEB-INF//JasperReports//Salary.jasper");
    jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportPath, parametersPDF, beanCollectionDataSource);
    httpServletResponse.addHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=Salary.pdf");
    ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();    
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, servletOutputStream);
```

Angular Side Code   -- you can use this code under your ajax request as you're using javascript

```
exportPDF(event){
this.showPageSpinner=true;
this.httpRestClient.fetchPDF("download_salary_report", this.payloadBean).subscribe(
  response => {
    var blob = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE');
    var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
    var edge = ua.indexOf('Edge/');

  if(msie > 0 || trident > 0 || edge > 0){
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob,'Salary.pdf');
}
else if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1){
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = "Salary.pdf";
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();

    window.setTimeout(function() {
      URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    }, 0);

}
  else{ 

  var link=document.createElement('a');
  link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  link.download="Salary.pdf";
  link.click();


  }
  this.showPageSpinner=false;
    },
  error=>{
  // show your message here

  });
```

}

Important - In request header add response type to 'arraybuffer' as 'json' otherwise it won't work

```
fetchPDF(url: string,data): Observable<any> {
this.getCredentials();
const authHeaders = this.createBasicAuthorizationHeader(this.credentials);
 return this.http.post(this.getApiUrl(url),data,{headers: authHeaders,'responseType'  : 'arraybuffer' as 'json'})
 }
```

It works in IE,Mozilla and Crome..